# Using an @if statement in an attribute doesn't work

Tags: c#, lambda, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm fairly new to C# and Blazor. I have the following attribute in a div tag.

```
 class="menu-header @if(expanded[j_ind]){expanded}"
```

I get the following error from Visual Studio 2019

> RZ9979: Code blocks delimited by '@{...}' like '@{ if(expanded[j_ind]){expanded} }' for attributes are no longer supported These features have been changed to use attribute suntax. Use 'attr="@(x => {...}"'.

Edit: The comment below has the solution:

```
class="menu-header @(expanded[j_ind] ? "expanded" : null)"
```

Comment: Based on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13024), you should be able to use: `class="menu-header @(expanded[j_ind] ? "expanded" : null)"`

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it in a wrong way, The correct way is

```
class="menu-header @(expanded[j_ind] ? "expanded" : "")"
```